# Unitary transformation matrix over Z_p

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have two vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ over $\mathbf{Z}_p^n$. I am wondering if there exists a unitary transformation matrix such that after applying the matrix to $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$, there exists an index $i$ that $\vec{x^\prime}_i =  \vec{y^\prime}_i$ (i.e., the transformed vectors have at least one equal element). Rotation doesn't work I guess because the result of rotation will not be in the space necessarily.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_p$ the $p$-adic integers?

Comment: let's say $p$ is prime, the field of integers modulo p

Comment: @Mohammad Mahzoun: How do you define a unitary matrix, mod $p\,$?

Comment: I am not sure if that is definable @quasi , I am wondering if such matrix exists to transform linearly the vectors over the $Z_p$.